# cannot get the ViewModel of a Partial View cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, partial-views

I have a PartialView on the index page as follows :-

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ImageUpload"); }
```

and the PartialView looks like this :-

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel

<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
      <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Now according to the declaration in the top of the PartialView, its supposed to go inside the ViewModels.ImageModel, and inside that class I have a constructor :-

```
public ImageModel()
{
   XDocument imageMetaData = XDocument.Load(uploadsDir + @"/ImagesMetaData.xml");
   var images = from image in imageMetaData.Descendants("image")
                select new Image(image.Element("filename").Value,
                image.Element("description").Value);
   this.AddRange(images.ToList<Image>());
}
```

However, for some reason, in the ImageUpload partial View, when I debug, I am not being redirected to this ViewModel constructor, and as so the model inside the PartialView is null.

Am I missing something here?

How can I get it to actually pass through my constructor?  Do I also need to do an @model in the main Index page (where is hosting the PartialView).

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel` is used to declare a strongly typed Model, but not instanciate it.

You should use

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ImageUpload", <yourmodel>); }
```

or more simple :

```
@Html.Partial("ImageUpload", <yourmodel>)
```

By the way, in your case:

```
@Html.Partial("ImageUpload", new ImageModel())
```

But carefull: your Model should be constructor less and not loading/parsing XML. This should be done in a Controller (and set in the Caching system?).

If you wish to keep your main view Model less, you can also create an Action with the Attribute ChildActionOnly for a partial rendering, and call it with `@Html.Action(...)`: it creates a new ControllerContext.

Comment: ok this works, can I set 2 answers? Both are correct. On another note, you said that my model should be constructor less.  I actually have a controller, so I sould do something like @Html.Partial("ImageUpload", "File"), File being the FileController

Comment: can you give ma a small example?  From the PartialView, how can I call the controller and populate the XML?

Comment: managed to do it with a Controller, thanks for the advice and all you help guys, very much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Chubyone.  The only problem I have is how to refresh this PartialView. After uploading the images, in the MainFunction, where shall I redirect it to?  I want to stay in my last opened View, for example the Projects Page.  Shall I open another thread with updated code?

Comment: I dont well understand your needs: caching problem, ajax request or redirect... But it sounds like a new problematic. Dont forget web is state less! Hope you ll find a way.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't setting the model of the partial view. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962.aspx

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ImageUpload", myModel); }
```

It's not the responsibility of the view to create the model, you will need to instantiate this in the associated controller of the view that contains the partial view.